# java getSession().setAttribute()

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I have to make a litle change to an existing project(tomcat and java WebApplication).
now, in loginForm, if users type correct login and password, it is Ok, 
to users wil be shown main page. But when any user types incorrect password,
or may be his account is temporarily locked, so to user again wil be shown loginform, 
user can not know why he cannot log in, by what cause he can not login. 
(for example "invalid username/password","user account locked",...).
now i want to insert the session error message that includes also causes of why user cannot log in.
insert(save) to session an attribute named "LoggingError".
i am writing as:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("LoggingError", message);
```

but when running application, in this line

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("LoggingError", message);
```

occurs error in web page:

```
type Exception report
message
description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.se.eee.security.EeeAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(EeeAuthenticationProvider.java:153)
    net.sf.acegisecurity.providers.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:159)
    net.sf.acegisecurity.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:49)
    net.sf.ace
...
...
```

here java code of EeeAuthenticationProvider.java

```
package com.se.eee.security;

import net.sf.acegisecurity.*;
import net.sf.acegisecurity.providers.AuthenticationProvider;
import net.sf.acegisecurity.providers.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import net.sf.acegisecurity.providers.dao.User;
import net.sf.acegisecurity.providers.dao.UsernameNotFoundException;
import net.sf.acegisecurity.providers.dao.event.*;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import com.se.eee.bus.*;
import com.se.eee.bus.SecurityManager;
import com.se.spring.datasource.core.MakeConnectionException;
import com.se.spring.ext.CurrentRequestContext;
import com.opensymphony.webwork.interceptor.SessionAware;
import com.opensymphony.webwork.interceptor.ServletRequestAware;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.util.Map;

public class EeeAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider, SessionAware, ServletRequestAware {
  private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(EeeAuthenticationProvider.class);
  private JDBCProperties jdbcProp;
  private ApplicationContext context;
  private SecurityManager securityManager;
  private HttpServletRequest request;

  public void setServletRequest(HttpServletRequest req) {
          this.request = req;
  }
  public void setSession(Map session) {
        //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
  }

  public void setSecurityManager(SecurityManager securityManager) {
    this.securityManager = securityManager;
  }

  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext)
      throws BeansException {
    this.context = applicationContext;
  }

  public void setJdbcProp(JDBCProperties jdbcProp) {
        this.jdbcProp = jdbcProp;
  }

  public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
    // Determine username
    // log.warn((authentication.isAuthenticated()?"Already Authenticated. Skip it!":"")+"authenticate: "+authentication);
  if(authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
      //log.warn("Already Authenticated. Skip it!");
    return authentication;
  }
  String username = "NONE_PROVIDED";

  if (authentication.getPrincipal() != null) {
    username = authentication.getPrincipal().toString();
  }

  if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
    username = ((UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
  }

  UserDetails user = null;
  com.se.eee.bus.User principal=null;

  try
    {
      JDBCProperties props = jdbcProp.deserialize();
      String input_passwords= authentication.getCredentials().toString();
      String[] psd = input_passwords.split(":");
      Filial fil = props.getFilial(psd[1]);

      String sgn = input_passwords;
      int i= sgn.indexOf(":", 1);
      sgn = sgn.substring(i+1,sgn.length());
      i= sgn.indexOf(":", 1);
      sgn = sgn.substring(i+1,sgn.length());

      if(fil==null)username=null;
      securityManager.makeConnect(username, psd[0], fil);
      user=new User(username, "skipped",true,true,true,true, new  GrantedAuthority[]{new GrantedAuthorityImpl("ROLE_USER")});
      //set connection for DataSource
      ContextDataBean dataBean=(ContextDataBean)CurrentRequestContext.get();
      dataBean.setUserKey(username+fil.id);

      principal=securityManager.getUserByLogin(username.toUpperCase());
      if(principal == null) throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Couldn't login.");

      principal.setLogin(username);
      principal.setPassword("******");
      //principal.setBranch(fil.id);

      if (principal.getBanktype().equals("055"))
      {
        if ( sgn!=null && sgn.length() != 0)
        {
            securityManager.insUserKey(principal.getBranch(), principal.getId(), sgn);
            com.se.eee.bus.Document docum = new com.se.eee.bus.Document();
            docum.setBranch(principal.getBranch());
            docum.setEmpId(principal.getId());
            docum.setErrCode("991");
            docum = securityManager.getAnswerUserKey(docum);
            if (!docum.getErrCode().equals("000")) throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Key code error. User: "+principal.getLogin());
        }
        else
        {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("error while inserting test key code. please touch i-key or check loginform.ftl. user: "+principal.getLogin());
        }
      }
    }
  catch (MakeConnectionException mex)
    {
      log.error(mex.getMessage());
      if (this.context != null) {
        context.publishEvent(new AuthenticationFailureUsernameOrPasswordEvent(authentication, new User("".equals(username)? "EMPTY_STRING_PROVIDED" : username, "*****", false, false, false, false, new GrantedAuthority[0])));
      }
      throw new BadCredentialsException("Couldn't login connection problem.");
    }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    Throwable cause=ex.getCause();
    String message=null;
    if(cause!=null)message = cause.getMessage();
    else message = ex.toString();
    log.error(message);

// здес я пытаюс написать в session
 request.getSession().setAttribute("LoggingError", message);
// но код не компилируется

    throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Couldn't login.");
  }
  return createSuccessAuthentication(principal, authentication, user);

  }
  protected Authentication createSuccessAuthentication(Object principal, Authentication authentication, UserDetails user) {
      UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(principal, authentication.getCredentials(), user.getAuthorities());
      result.setDetails((authentication.getDetails() != null) ? authentication.getDetails() : null);
      result.setAuthenticated(true);
      return result;
  }

  public boolean supports(Class aClass) {
    if (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(aClass)) return true;
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: what is exactly the error you have ? we need more details to help you

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could post the error you get when trying to compile.

Comment: Apart from the problem, you normally use the request scope for this, not the session scope.

Comment: I have edited the message, please read after th line "Newer entered"

Comment: -1 for having the temerity to put `<blink>` tags in your question

Comment: You do realize that the trace says the error is in a line that is _one more_ than the total number of lines in your pasted code? (Check if `request` is null, and if `request.getSession()` returns null.)

Answer (score 0):

If your request object is a HttpServletRequest object then this should work.

If this isn't the problem can you send the exact code snippet (shouldn't need the whole program) and the exact error message?

Comment: I have edited the message, please read after th line "Newer entered".

Comment: @Hamza - What statement is at line 153 in your probram?  I can tell it's somewhere in the authenticate method but not sure where.  If it's in the catch block can you do a stack trace to see what's generating the error.  It looks like you've not initialized some variable and that is what is throwing the null pointer exception but I'm not able to trim it down to exactly what variable.  I'd suggest narrowing down the exact line that is throwing the null pointer and make sure that you're initializing everything.  If that doesn't work give the info I asked for above.

Answer (score 0):

this should work.

```
request.getSession(true).setAttribute("LoggingError", message);
```

Comment: The original call should not return `null` - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29

Answer (score 0):

Is your authentication provider specified as `prototype` scope bean? Not sure how Struts / WebWork is exactly integrated with Spring, but if your bean is `singleton`, it can not work.

In other words, make sure `setServletRequest` is called.

And by the way this application must be pretty old, if it has such package names as it has.